# Operational error while trying to connect my MySQL database to pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

I have finished my django project and I want to test it out on PythonAnywhere everything was fine until mysql database connection shows an error

I have paid subscription.

> OperationalError at /home/
> (1044, "Access denied for user 'almx98'@'%' to database 'almx98'")

I have a lot of records that I don't want to lose.

pythonanywhere venv settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'almx98',
    'HOST': 'almx98.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'USER': 'almx98',
    'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
}
```

}

server connection settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL database names on PythonAnywhere have form: `<username>$<something>` Your default one would look like that: `almx98$default` but you might have created some other one that you want to use in your web app.